# Need regex to redact valid email addresses but not ones that start with certain words, can't use lookarounds

Tags: regex, re2

I am attempting to make adjustments to a regex that matches when it finds a string that matches the structure of a valid email address. This is the starting point, which, as you can see, is pretty straightforward:

`\b([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-\._]*[A-Za-z0-9])@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\b`

However, I want to rewrite this so that email addresses starting with certain words (let's use "blern" for example) cause the email address to not match and therefore not be redacted. These trigger words may appear as a prefix on the email address (blernsoandso@gmail.com) or as a prefix with a slash (blern/soandso@gmail.com) and both instances need to be handled by the regex. Some email addresses also may have "." in the address (blern/firstname.lastname@gmail.com) and those also need to be handled correctly. I had previously attempted to address all of this with a lookbehind and a lookahead, as in the following regex:

`(?<!(blern/|other/))(?!(blern|other))\b([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-\._]*[A-Za-z0-9])@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\.)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\b`

The issue is that the engine that is running this regex is RE2, and lookarounds aren't supported. So I need to accomplish all of those revisions I mentioned without using a lookahead or lookbehind. Does anyone have any insight into this issue? I'll also accept any critiques on the original email regex if you have any.

Comment: That shows essential lacking regex knowledge (escaping inside classes, repeated code), plus it won't accept valid addresses like `abc-@localhost` (ending dash in account is allowed, and the host part does not need to be a domain); it should at least look like this: `\b[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9._-]*[A-Za-z0-9-])?@(([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\b`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm new to regex